# Create UIImage in the place of the user finger with UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I am using this code in an `IBAction` to create a `UIImageView` with a **touch drag inside** `UIButton`:

```
-(IBAction) addNewPhoto:(id)sender{

switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 0:{

        imageMove = [UIImage imageNamed:@"knet.jpg"];

         holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, imageMove.size.width, imageMove.size.height)];
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
        [imageview setImage:imageMove];
        [holderView addSubview:imageview];

        UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
        [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

        UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
        [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [holderView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
        [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
        [holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

        [self.view addSubview:holderView];

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
        [superView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 550)];
        //[holderView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 550)];
        //holderView.alpha = 1;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        imageMove = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];

        //..........similar to case 0 but another picture
         }
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

The buttons is inside a `scrollView`, What I'm looking for is, the Image should be created where the user dragged his/her finger off the button and still be able move it around without removing his/her finger.

I used the source code for moving, zooming, rotating the image from this [Blog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/) with a modification on creating the image with a button not with UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Shamlan, you do know if an answer helps you can upvote, if it serves as a solution to your question, you should tick it (press the tick silhouette below the question voting tools)

Comment: @RohanKapur yes i know about this tool, but i didn't find the answer yet, and thanx for your editing but what am looking for is CREATING the UIImage with an IBAction in the first place not moving it, am ok with moving, there are dozens of answered moving questions, i made my homework for that ;)

Comment: You want to let the user draw with his/her finger and create an image from that?

Comment: @nielsbot i want the image to be created where the user tapped on the screen exactly where the button is, to be more clear: I'm using the above code in many buttons. so, i don't know what to put instead of the 0,0 here `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];`

Comment: can you describe it another way or post a picture? not sure I understand what you want to do

Comment: @nielsbot lets say this case: single view app with one button on the centre of the screen, the button is set as touch drag exit "so we don't know where the user finger will end up", the IBAction of the button is to create an image exactly where the user ended up his finger after dragging it from the button, ask me if its still not clear "sorry english is not my first language :)".

Comment: so you want to find the intersection of the user's touch path leaving the button with the frame of the button?

Comment: @nielsbot yes "i think", create the image where the user ended up his/her finger, and the button stays in its position.

Comment: Just add my long-press gesture recognizer to your button, keep checking the state and when the state is equal to `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` grab the location from `[gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for that. If you add the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to the main view (the holderView's super view), you can detect the state of the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in the called selector to determine what to do. The `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` has the state `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` if you move your finger after the gesture is recognised:

```
- (void)createNewImage:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // create a new image, add to the view, and position at the location of the touch
        // store a reference to it in an ivar
    } else if (([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)) {
        // move the image stored in the ivar
    } else {
        // set the ivar to nil
        // add the standard gesture recognisers to the new image
    }
}
```

To explain further, add a new variable to your view controller:

```
@interface ViewController
{
    UIView *_newView;
}
@end
```

then add this to your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(createNewImage:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
```

Then add the method `createNewImage` to the view controller:

```
- (void)createNewImage:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) { //press has begun    
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"knet.jpg"];
        UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
        UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
        [imageview setImage:image];
        [holderView addSubview:imageview];

        [holderView setCenter:CGPointMake(translation.x, translation.y)];
        _newView = holderView;

        [self.view addSubview:holderView];
    } else if (([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)) { //finger is moving

        [_newView setCenter:CGPointMake(translation.x, translation.y)];

    } else { //finger lifted off to end the long press

        // here, you'll have to add all the other gesture recognisers to 
        // _newView in case if the new image is moved
        _newView = nil;
    }
}
```

A side point: I've kept your `holderView` view hierarchy, but it seems redundant, you can just drag a `UIImageView` around without the holder view.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm using this code inside an IBAction, i was trying to fit your lines in my code but i couldn't do that .. would explain in more details please :))

Comment: Oh right, no you should add the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in your  view controllers `viewDidLoad` since you're adding the gesture recognizer to that view, not the image.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation but my code is inside an `IBAction` sets with **touch drag exit** with `switch case` inside it for multiple buttons, I've update my code so you can understand my case :))

Comment: OK, but according to your question you want the long-press to create the image. This means the gesture recognizer needs to be added to the view that creates the image.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i didn't mean a long-press, what i need is when the user tap on a button an image should be created directly where he tapped "button position" and still be abel to move it without taking off his/her finger, and because we have many buttons linked with one IBAction to create different images "and these buttons are inside a scrollview" we don't know where exactly he/she tapped, the long-press code you placed is doing perfect except that what i want is: the image should be created directly.

Comment: Have you looked at touch drag inside and touch drag outside events?

Comment: yes i did, **touch drag inside** is creating the image when i tap on it and drag, and **touch drag outside** is creating too many images as log as i drag and that is not needed, in both cases; the image is created in the upper left corner of the screen because of this `holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, imageMove.size.width, imageMove.size.height)];` the only thing needed now is to change the 0,0 to the place of the user finger, and continue to be able to move it without taking off his/her finger.

Comment: or make something similar to this `[[holderView view] setCenter:CGPointMake(X, Y)];`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more) from Ray Wenderlich. It provides everything you want, **dragging**, this is what you are clearly looking for, it provides a solution to drag the image with the finger and even add a cool velocity effect to it! pinch to zoom, touching, rotating. You can download the sample code from there, this helped me get a grip on gesture recognizers.

Rohan

Comment: This article is showing how to move the uiimage while its already there when the app lunches, what am looking for is creating the image exactly where the users taped "the button position".

Comment: @Shamlan And the button can move?

Comment: no the button stays, but because the button is set to touch drag exit the image should be created where the user finish his dragging "thats we dont know where".